# What's the difference between these codes? Swift

Tags: swift

This code will result in an error.

```swift
var weatherForecast: String = "sunny"
if let forecast = weatherForecast {
    print("The forecast is \(forecast).")
} else {
    print("No forecast available.")
}
```

This code runs normally

```swift
let album = "Red"
let albums = ["Reputation", "Red", "1989"]
if let position = albums.firstIndex(of: album) {
    print("Found \(album) at position \(position).")
}
```

```swift
if let forecast = weatherForecast
```

```swift
if let position = albums.firstIndex(of: album)
```

What's the difference...?

Comment: Could you share the compiler error on the first one? There should be an important keyword "optional", which is a basic concept of Swift.

Comment: The compiler message is “Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'” – that gives a strong hint ...

Answer (score 3):

For the first code `if let` is not needed as `weatherForecast` is not an optional value.